# ImportError: cannot import name 'Required' from 'typing_extensions', no me toma el metodo Required

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como ven en el titulo, el metodo `Required` de la libreria `typing_extensions` me tira error como que no lo puede importar.
El error completo es:

```
from typing_extensions import Required
ImportError: cannot import name 'Required' from 'typing_extensions' 
(C:\Users\matia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site 
packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

Ya probe lo que dicen otras respuestas, como hacer `pip install typing_extensions` y me realizo la instalacion, pero este error no me deja continuar y no se como encontrarle la vuelta. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te ocurre este error puede ser por varias cosas, algunas de ellas:

- Tienes instalada una versión de la librería que no es en la que se encuentra la función.
- Estás utilizando una versión de Python que no es en la que la has instalado.
- Hay un fallo en el propio paquete.
- Sencillamente la función no existe.

En tu caso debe de ser la última opción que he puesto, ya que si nos vamos a [Github](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions) podemos ver que la función `Required` que estás tratando de importar, **no existe en la librería** y por tanto no puede ser importado.